# how to use getProcAddress() without type cast?

Tags: c++, c, dynamic

I am try to find address of variables using getprocaddress. But i am getting problem in this.Problem is that i stored name of variable in a char buff[100] one by one as in loop. That time i have no idea of type of variable. so how it possible to use this without type cast. i try to use void * ptr for avoiding the type cast. I got value of ptr is zero.

```
void *ptr;
HMODULE hdl;
char buff[100];
char word[100];
char ch1;
int     total_item=0;
META_INFO_FILE=fopen("META.txt","r");

do {

    ch1 = fscanf(META_INFO_FILE,"%s",word); 

    if ((word[0]== '_'))
    {   
        strcpy(META_buff,word+1);
        hdl = GetModuleHandle (NULL); // handle of executable
        ptr =GetProcAddress (hdl, META_buff);
        total_item++;
    } while (ch1 != EOF);
```

thanks

Comment: Are you saying that you get a good value in `ptr` if you use a cast?  I suspect that casting (or not casting) has nothing to do with your problem, so I wonder why you're asking about that?  I'm guessing that your problem is that you're asking `GetProcAddress()` to resolve names that aren't exported by the module.

Comment: @MichaelBurr: i used this function to give the direct  variable name with casting then i got the value but without casting i didnt get. in this module  my problem is that which u understood

Comment: BTW you should at least submit properly formatted code.

Comment: @A_Gupta: if you have a working example with a cast you want to get rid of, you should post it along with the non-working code that you're trying to move to.  Also, you should try to post code that's as close to compilable as possible. Fo example, your posted `do`/`while` (or the `if`) statement isn't properly formed.

Answer (score 2):

Well, your `ptr` is NULL because you aren't finding the name. That is completely unrelated to casting. (You may have to fiddle with DLLExport and such things to make your symbols visible, for example) If that is your question, then we're done here. [By the way, in your example, `buff` looks like a local variable. They can not, by definition be exported from a DLL, since this kind of variable is ONLY available when the function is "in the active callstack". You can't really export symbols to variables that don't exist at the time of exporting them...

But I suspect you are asking "if I can find the symbol, how do I use it".

The short answer is "you can't do that".

The long answer is sitll "you can't do that", but with a bit of a possible solution. You will have to, in one way or another, encode in your `META_INFO_FILE` what kind of data you have. At least if you want to do anything other than call `memcpy(ptr, somestuff, somesize)` on the result.

I also think there may be a BETTER way to do this. At least if it's your own code you are dealing with - and if you are "patching" someone else's code, well shame on you.

For example, you could introduce your own symboltable, which HAS information on what type it is, etc.

Eg:

```
enum Type { CHAR_TYPE, INT_TYPE, /* more types here ... */ }
struct 
{
   char *name;
   Type type;
   char *size;
   void *ptr;
}
mysymbols [] = 
{
   { "buff", CHAR_TYPE, sizeof(buff), &buff },
   { "other", INT_TYPE, sizeof(other), &other },
};
```

Now, you can search that list, and then use a "switch" to cast to the correct type.

Comment: Meta_info_file is nothing but extract all the variables from .map file that only contains compile time address and name of varibles.

Comment: Ok, but that is generated based on debug information, not DLL export symbols, right? (Use `dumpbin /exports myfile.exe` to inspect what symbols are exported)

Comment: However, more importantly, what are you trying to do? Your question is vague with regards to what you are actually trying to achieve - it's a typical XY question, where you think X is the right solution, and thus ask "Why doesn't X work right for me?", when you should be asking "How do I solve problem Y?", where we may be able to come up with some better solution.

Comment: Yes, dumpbin is part of the Visual Studio compiler (at least in 2005 and 2010 versions, which is the ones I've used)

Comment: It lists the symbols your .exe or .dll is exporting. Which is why it's different from a .map file - which is my point.